# Delete image from folder using data list

Tags: c#, asp.net, button, datalist

I display some images in a DataList by getting the images from folder. Now, I want to delete the image in folder when I click the Delete button in my Datalist.

My problem is that I'm not able to get the file name from:

```
string fileName = e.CommandArgument.ToString();
```

I tried several solutions but did not get a right solution.

**Html Markup:**

```
<asp:DataList OnDeleteCommand="gvImages_DeleteCommand" ID="gvImages" RepeatColumns="5" 
              RepeatDirection="Horizontal" GridLines="Horizontal" runat="server" 
              BorderColor="#336699" BorderStyle="Solid" ShowHeader="true">
    <ItemTemplate>
    <center>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td style="width: 90px; height: 90px">
                    <img id="PICID" runat="server" src='<%# Container.DataItem %>' alt='' 
                         style="height: 100px; width: 100px;" /><br />
                    <asp:Button ID="Delete" Height="22px" CommandName="Delete" 
                                Width="100px" runat="server" Text="Delete Picture" /><br />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </center>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:DataList>
```

**Code-behind:**

```
protected void gvImages_DeleteCommand(object source, DataListCommandEventArgs e)
{
    //you can hold filename on Button's  CommandArgument 

    string fileName = e.CommandArgument.ToString();

   // here i can not get the file name to delete it from the folder

    File.Delete(Server.MapPath(fileName));

    FileInfo fInfo;

    fInfo = new FileInfo(fileName);

    fInfo.Delete();

    gvImages.DataBind();
}
```

Comment: Is `Server.MapPath(fileName)` returning the correct path? Also do you get any permission exceptions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add `asp:Image` control in your DataList and try it:

**Html Markup:** `FilePath` is a column name in your DataSource.

```
<asp:Image ID="PICID" runat="server" 
           ImageUrl='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "FilePath") %>' />
```

**Code-behind:** In `gvImages_DeleteCommand` event like:

```
string url = ((Image)gvImages.Items[e.Item.ItemIdex].FindControl("PICID")).ImageUrl;

string path = Server.MapPath(url);

if (File.Exists(path))
{
    File.Delete(path); // deletes file from folder
}
```